# Convert '04/21/19' to '2019-04-14T08:54:27.096Z' format

Tags: javascript

i would like to convert this date string format '04/21/19' to this format '2019-04-14T08:54:27.096Z'

Comment: What problem are you having? You might want to check out the moment.js library.

Comment: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `new Date(string)`:

```
var newFormat = new Date('04/21/19')
```

This returns

```
Date 2019-04-21T03:00:00.000Z
```

Since there is no time information, the time will be set to 00:00 local time (I am at -3:00 when UTC is 0:00)